# ¿Como actualizar el estado de una form en un Context Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo la siguiente `<form>` que recoge en su estado lo que se escribe en los dos inputs que tiene:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '', location: ""};

    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    this.handleLocation = this.handleLocation.bind(this);
  }
  handleName(event){
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
  }
  handleLocation(event){
    this.setState({location: event.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="user-form">
       
        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Name: </label>
          <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName} className="input" />
        </div>

        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Location: </label>
          <input value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleLocation} className="input" />
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Lo que quiero es que lo que se recoja en el estado, se lea como `props` en los componentes Location.js y Name.js:

```js
const Location = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
        <strong>Location</strong>: {}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

const Name = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
        <strong>Name</strong>: {}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Como están separados en varios archivos y tendría que pasar props 3 veces, quería usar el React Context y así aprender como se usa pero he visto ya 2 tutoriales y leído los docs (intentado) y no me queda claro como integrar estas dos cosas. (La Form y el Context Provider)

He añadido lo siguiente, el poner las funciones de recoger nombre y localización, en el contexto del Provider:

```js
class MyProvider extends React.Component{
  state = {
    name: "Javier",
    location: "Stack_Over_Flow"
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={{ 
        state: this.state,
        handleTName: (e) => this.setState({
          name: e.target.value
        }),
        handleTLocation: (e) => this.setState({
          location: e.target.value
        })
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </myContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**Pero como las llevo a la Form es mi gran duda**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ScotchInfoBar from "./ScotchInfoBar";

import "./styles.css";

const myContext = React.createContext()

class MyProvider extends React.Component{
  state = {
    name: "Javier",
    location: "Stack_Over_Flow"
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={{ 
        state: this.state,
        handleTName: (e) => this.setState({
          name: e.target.value
        }),
        handleTLocation: (e) => this.setState({
          location: e.target.value
        })
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </myContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const Location = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Display user's location from Context */}
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
      <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <p><strong>Location:</strong> {context.state.location}</p>
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
const Name = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
        <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> {context.state.name}</p>
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '', location: ""};

    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    this.handleLocation = this.handleLocation.bind(this);
  }
  handleName(event){
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
  }
  handleLocation(event){
    this.setState({location: event.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="user-form">
        {/* Change user's name in context */}
        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Name: </label>
          <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName} className="input" />
        </div>

        {/* Change user's location in context */}
        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Location: </label>
          <input value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleLocation} className="input" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <MyProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <Form />
        <Name />
        <Location />
      </div>
      <ScotchInfoBar />
    </div>
    </MyProvider>
  );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Al final era más simple de lo que pensaba, no tuve en cuenta que **se puede añadir Consumers tantos como sea necesario**, así que lo apliqué también a la Form usando las funciones de recoger estado que hice en el Provider

```js
const Location = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Display user's location from Context */}
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
      <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <p><strong>Location:</strong> {context.state.location}</p>
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
const Name = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
      <h2 className="is-size-4">
        <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> {context.state.name}</p>
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

class Form extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="user-form">
        {/* Change user's name in context */}
        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Name: </label>
          <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <input value={context.state.name} onChange={context.handleTName} className="input" />
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
        </div>

        {/* Change user's location in context */}
        <div className="input-item">
          <label className="label">Update Location: </label>
          <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <input value={context.state.location} onChange={context.handleTLocation} className="input" />
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: También podes usar el hook de context para consumirlo https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Así es mi primer intento con context fue mucho más complejo de lo necesario y no funcionaba. Cuando lo simplifiqué funcionó perfecto.